# ReSharper decompiler - can I use it for standalone assemblies?

Tags: .net, resharper, decompiling, resharper-6.0

I have ReSharper 6.1 and can use the **Navigate To > Decompiled Sources** command to decompile .NET assemblies for which I do not have source code.  This is excellent when I want to take a peek inside an assembly which I have referenced in my code.

Is there a way (as in Reflector and ILSpy) to simply give ReSharper a standalone assembly file and decompile it?  I want to take a deployed DLL from a server and view the decompiled code so I can verify it is the version I think it is.

(I am fully aware that the fact I am asking this means our versioning process leaves a lot to be desired, but that's a different topic!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the standalone tool [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) for this task. It uses the same technology as ReSharper.

Comment: I had seen that was available, but assumed that it was simply a subset of the functionality available in ReSharper and that I was failing to find a menu item that would enable me to do it.  Clearly that isn't the case!

Answer (score 1):

Use [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) which is a standalone application based on ReSharper decompiling engine (or the other way around, as you like)

Comment: I was even faster then the JetBrains marketing lead. Not bad. Do I get a commission? Hehe...

Comment: I see you work for JetBrains ... is there any reason why this ability isn't built into ReSharper itself?  After all, the decompiling engine is all there, surely it would just need some kind of GUI.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Well done and an upvote from me. It's no problem though to be faster than me as I'm a total slowpoke.

Comment: @SirCrispalot I guess integrating this into VS would be an overkill: VS (and ReSharper) is intended to work with solutions, projects, and references, not with individual files. As far as I know, for use cases like yours, a common solution implies using a standalone decompiler and associating .dll files with it.